# How to delete 1 row out of 2 exact rows in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Other answer on internet is not very clear, so I ask this question again.

Again, I have a table tb1

```
ID
114035
114035
```

How to delete 1 row & keep other?

The result should be

```
ID
114035
```

Comment: You can't (or at least shouldn't), you'll need a unique identifier.

Comment: Where is the 'other answer on internet'?  If it's on the SO site, perhaps ask for further clarification in that thread...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about which one is removed:

```
DELETE FROM tb1 WHERE ID = 114035 LIMIT 1;
```

Otherwise find out what differentiates the one you want to keep and use that in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: if you DO care on the other hand, use more specific constraints that are unique to your record, like `DELETE FROM tb1 WHERE ID = 114035 AND NAME='Somename';`

Comment: how to do if the tb1 is from other select "select ID from MainTable where ID=114035"

Comment: @MinhHai I'm not sure I understand `select ID from MainTable where ID=114035` will *always* return `114035`.

Comment: @jim Without a primary key that could return 0 or more rows.

Comment: But all those results would be 114035 so why select in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE tb1 ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (ID);
```

---

Add `UNIQUE` index to the column using `ALTER` and also use `IGNORE` keyword

---

This will delete duplicate entries and also no `duplicate` entry in future.

---

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

---

Update after OP's comment

Drop `Unique` constraint

```
DROP INDEX idx_name ON tb1
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE tb1 DROP INDEX idx_name
```

Comment: actually this ID column is the foreign key that reference to OK of other table

Comment: the problem is that i used data from other source, so it messed up, I can't ignore cos it will be dangerous

Comment: @MinhHai check updated answer .Drop the key after getting duplicate entry deleted .

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a temporary table to store the rows you don't want deleted.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp ( id INT );

INSERT INTO tmp ( id )
SELECT id
FROM tbl
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

Then remove all of rows you consider to be duplicates.

```
DELETE FROM tbl
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM tmp 
    WHERE tmp.id = tbl.id
);
```

Finally 'replace' the rows with the ones stored in the temporary table from earlier.

```
INSERT INTO tbl ( id )
SELECT id
FROM tmp;
```